# Foreign Key with a default value that doesn't exist in primary table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my situation.  I have a table where the value of a column  can be NULL, 0, or a value from anther table. The other table does not have a 0 value for any rows.

What is my best option?

1) Don't add the FK.

2) add a 0 record to the foreign table.

3) something else.

I can't change the 0 value to a null.  and the 0 represents a valid value.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus added tags, but it's more of a general SQL best practice question.  At least for me.

Comment: Yes, but for point 3, it's important ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 0 is a valid value, I would personally add 0 as a record of the "foreign table".

Or 3) use a CHECK CONSTRAINT instead of a FOREIGN KEY.

But the answer can't be 1) or 2) or 3) as a "best practice generic answer" : it depends on your needs (what must happen when something, related to your table, is deleted in the foreign table is one of the most important thing to consider).

Weakness of check constraints :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx

> CHECK constraints are not validated during DELETE statements.
>   Therefore, executing DELETE statements on tables with certain types of
>   check constraints may produce unexpected results. For example,
>   consider the following statements executed on table CheckTbl.

Comment: Ends up that instead of adding the record, we'll make the 0's a null.  That being said, I didn't know the issue with deletes on the check contraint.  Not too mention that I like FK's for the schema relationship indicator.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally look to the schema - either this column is a foreign key or it isn't - it sounds as if you're trying to use the column for 2 different things ("0 represents a valid value").
If you can't change the schema to add a genuine FK column then go with solution 1 as the next best (IMO)

Comment: Can I +2 this answer? @Dayton: You are actually using the column for 3 things: NULL for whatever that means in your design, 0 as a valid (special?) value and all the rest values as an FK. Don't do that. Re-examine your schema.

Comment: I only wish I could reaxamine the schema.  I specifically asked to change the 0 to something else, but that will break the web app.

Answer (score 0):

A check constraint with an `EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM OtherTable WHERE fkv=v) OR v=0` would be an option. However, For performance reasons a real foreign key is always preferred. (SQL Server can and will make use of a declared foreign key relationship during query optimization often leading to much faster queries.)

Also, as Raphaël Althaus mentioned, check constraints are only checked when you insert or update the record in the child table. A delete of a parent record goes without consequences, even when there are existing children. (For that you could add a trigger however)

All in all adding the "0" record and declaring a real foreign key is your best bet.

Comment: I don't think that SQL-Server (or any other SQL-product) provides the functionality of `CHECK` constraints with subqueries. (Actually MS-Access provides them but not really confident that they work 100% as expected).

Comment: You are correct, sub-queries are not supported directly, but you can wrap the functionality into a function